# How to show dialogue for network change states?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, dialog

I have a code for network change state in android. but now problem is that code shows the snack-bar when network state changed. i want that it will show dialogue box when network state get changed. I already done everything. i just want instead of snack-bar dialogue will be shown.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangedReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
                String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";

                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_dashboard), "Network Status: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `AlertDialog.Builder` to create an alert dialog instead of `Snackbar`. Something along the following lines should work,

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangedReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
        String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";

        //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_dashboard), "Network Status: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple AlertDialog that you can use:

```
 public static Dialog createSimpleOkDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

        return alertDialog.create();
    }
```